# Install Driver Cuda

Tags: cuda, nvidia, xserver

I have to install CUDA for Linux.
I downloaded the toolkit, drivers and SDK.
But when I try to install the CUDA drivers, I get the following error:

> ERROR: You appear to be running an X server; please exit X before
>            installing.

I use Ubuntu 10.04 LTS (32 bit)
How can I solve this?

Comment: What Linux distribution and version are you using?

Comment: sorry, i forget this! i use Ubuntu 10.04 LTS (32 bit)

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu 10.04, assuming you're using the Gnome desktop environment, you need to stop the `gdm` daemon.  From a terminal, run the following:

```
sudo service gdm stop
```

This will stop the `gdm` daemon and throw you to a bare terminal (if you want to start `gdm` again, just replace the `stop` argument with a `start` argument).  Install the CUDA toolkit, drivers, and SDK as you normally would.  When you're done, reboot the computer to make sure you're using the new drivers.

```
sudo reboot
```

Comment: This procedure brings me to a black screen, that makes checking battery and nothing else.
Example:
black screen and white cursor blinking, not allowing me to make any kind of operation. Thanks

Comment: You probably need to switch to a different terminal screen...try `Ctrl`-`Alt`-`F1`. And if you're on a laptop, you might need to use the function key to make the F-buttons do what they're supposed to do, instead of the extra functionality that they sometimes have (like brightness, etc.).

Comment: in this way i resolve this problem, but when i try to install appear this alert: "The distribuition-provided pre-install script failed! continue installation aniway?" i say "yes", but not work!

Comment: this istallation is blocked when it try to resolve X conflict in /usr

Comment: I'm not sure what that means, so I don't know if I can provide any more help.